# Share Referral object Directly on WhatsApp, FaceBook, Twitter without using ShareSheetStyle in android

Tags: android, branch, branch.io

Right now I am using ShareSheetStyle to share the BranchUniversalObject, but now I need to share BranchUniversalObject to WhatsApp or twitter etc using Android Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a answer

```
branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(this, linkProperties, new BranchLinkCreateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            Log.i("MyApp", "got my Branch link to share: " + url);
        }
    }
});
```

This will give us a url to share. Just need to create a Intent and start sharing.

[offical Documentation](https://dev.branch.io/features/content-sharing/advanced/android/#creating-dynamic-links-without-the-share-sheet)